# Why can't I scroll to the top of page using react-scrollable-anchor in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure where I messed up so I can't scroll to top when I click a HOME anchor on navigation bar on top of screen. For example, I can scroll to CONTACT page when I click the anchor from HOME page, but when I try to go back to HOME page by clicking the HOME anchor, it stops at between HOME page and second page, not all the way up. I tried anything I know and I can google but with no luck.

This is my app.js

```
import ScrollableAnchor from 'react-scrollable-anchor'

<Router>
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">

        <div className="navigationLists">
          {navList}
        </div>
        <ScrollableAnchor id={'HOME'} >
          <Home />
        </ScrollableAnchor>
      </div>
      <ScrollableAnchor id={'CONTACT'}>
        <Contact />
      </ScrollableAnchor>
    </div>
</Router>
```

This is my App.scss:

```
.App {
     text-align: center; 

     .App-header {
         position: relative;
         height: 650px; // This might need to change
         min-height: 500px;
         width: 100%;
         background: #161415 url(./images/aha.gif) no-repeat top center;
         background-size: contain ;
         -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
         text-align: center;
         overflow: hidden;

         .navigationLists {
             width: 80%;
             margin: 2% 10%;
             display: flex;
             justify-content: space-around;
             list-style-type: none;
             position: fixed;
             top: 0;
         }
     }
 }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your first ScrollableAnchor is inside the App-header in your structure, is it normal?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lx8nw361m9

Comment: I do this because I have my background image setup in .App-header, I guess I have bad structure design?

Comment: Alright. I was messed up with my bad structure. Now it's working! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the structure is important, or you will have hard time to debug CSS, please go look up Jayffe's example